# When I tried to export power apps table data into azure storage using azure synapse link will it costs for write operation in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-synapse, azure-billing

I have exported my power apps dataverse table into azure storage (as a CSV file) by using Azure synapse Link feature in power apps. It works fine but what is my question is, will it costs for writing data in azure storage? if yes means what Tier it will choose?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can access through data lake gen 2 storage account with hot tier. In comparison to the cool tier, the hot tier allows us faster access to the blobs in a storage account but is more expensive. The default value for any new blob is in the hot tier.

1. After assigning tier, you can connect the Data Lake Storage Gen2 storage container containing the exported Data verse data to Power BI.
2. Before connection you need **`Power BI Desktop`**,**`Azure Synapse Link for Dataverse`**,**`Storage Account Access.`**
   For storage account access you need any one of the role like storage blob contributor or storage blob owner.

You must enable Hierarchical namespace in your storage account, and suggest configuring replication to read-access geo-redundant storage (RA-GRS) features.

**Reference:**
[Analyze Microsoft Dataverse exported to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 data with Power BI - Power Apps | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/export-to-data-lake-data-powerbi)

Comment: venkat what I'm asking is writing data from table into azure data lake by azure synapse link not for us.

Comment: Please refer this https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/storage/tables/